# Custom display templates for DataType.EmailAddress and DataType.PhoneNumber

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to create custom display templates for the datatypes EmailAddress and PhoneNumber.

DisplayTemplates are resolved using the model type. The DataType however can not be resolved here. I can set the model type to string to create a custom display template for any string, however what is passed in is a string and not the property of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however what is passed in is a string and not the property of an object.

Yes, but you have access to the metadata:

```
ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName
```

For example you could have the following string template:

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName == DataType.PhoneNumber.ToString())
{ 
    <div>This is a phone number template</div>
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox(
        "", 
        ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
        new { @class = "text-box single-line" }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works nicely! Your example is for a EditorTemplate though ;-)

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't pay attention :-)