# MVC 4 EmailAddress - String EditorTemplate not being used

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've come across a strange issue including the `[EmailAddress]` DataAnnotation, say:

```
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

With a `EditorTemplate/String.cshtml` works fine.

However:

```
[EmailAddress]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

This completely stops picking up the `String.cshtml` file, which is not ideal for my scenario. Any ideas out there as to why this is happening, and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a display template for EmailAddress, for an example how see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145088/custom-display-templates-for-datatype-emailaddress-and-datatype-phonenumber).
There are also Nuget packages available that add display templates for all HTML5 input types.

Comment: Excellent, this works with the EmailAddress.cshtml template. Thank you.

Comment: For clarification-sake of others who find this answer, you can add an EditorTemplate called EmailAddress.cshtml in the EditorTemplates folder, and it will be used instead of the String.cshtml EditorTemplate for properties marked with the `[EmailAddress]` Data Annotation.